# Using jquery append or remove on an element with child input elements changes them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

Using jquery 1.9.1; maybe later versions differ?
But the problem seems to be that the input elements revert to their original values, even though the user has changed them. I have the same problem if I do something equivalent in straight javascript using innerHTML. The problem seems to be that the html shows the defaultValue (for type=text) or the defaultChecked (for type=checkbox), and those end up being instantiated as the value or checked in the modified child elements. This seems like a bug; in any case it violates the principle of least surprise.

Comment: When you "append", are you making a copy, or moving the element?

Comment: I'm appending (or removing) a <tr> element to (or from) a <tbody>. The <tr> elements already present (or remaining) contain <input> elements that are changed, reverting to their .defaultValue or .defaultChecked. The .innerHTML of the <tbody> shows the <input> elements with their defaults, not their current state.

Comment: That still doesn't make it clear whether you're *moving* or *copying* the elements in question. Please [edit] your question to show the relevant code.

Comment: I have not been able to reproduce this problem using jQuery append or remove, and must conclude that they work fine and that it was only when attempting to append by replacing .innerHTML with .innerHTML+newstuff that I saw the problem. Referencing earlier versions of my problematic code seems to verify this, although I don't have a complete change record.

Answer (score 1):

My workaround is to perform:

```
$(element).find('input[type=text]').each(function(i, o) {
  o.defaultValue = o.value;
})
```

and

```
$(element).find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(i, o) {
  o.defaultChecked = o.checked;
})
```

before doing the `$(element).append` or `$(element).remove`.